# Problem calling method of object stored inside a list

Tags: python, oop

I am pretty new to Python and in an attempt to learn, I decided to code a project which includes the making of a deck of cards (it's blackjack, I guess many people do this when learning). Simply put, the code recursively makes all the cards based on the defined cards class.

However, when I want to call the list and check that the cards are actually in the correct order (by calling a random element and calling the description method) I get an error.

```
class Card():
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def description(self):
        return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"

values = ["ace", 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"jack","queen","king"]
colors = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Spades","Clubs"]
deck = [card(value,color) for value in values for color in colors]
deck[3].description()
```

I would expect to get the description of the fourth instance of the cards created. However, I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-56-567b42634c58> in <module>
     12 c = Card("ace","Spades")
     13 c.description()
---> 14 deck[3].description()

AttributeError: 'card' object has no attribute 'description'
```

I don't why there is an error, the code makes instances of the class so I would expect to be able to call the method/attribute (actually it says .description is an attribute but isn't it a method? I don't quite get the difference...)

I couldn't find someone with a similar problem and looking up this error in general doesn't help my either. If there is a similar question out there, excuse my redundancy! Is there a simple mistake I am making?
Any comment would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your class is called `Card` but you're setting that list with `card` which is probably something else in your code, and you error shows lines of code not in your code example

Comment: Good catch, Kinda embarrassing...

Answer (score 1):

Your class is called `Card` but you're setting that list with `card` which is probably something else in your code, and you error shows lines of code not in your code example.

*Credit to Ofer Sadan in the comments. Formalizing it into an answer.*

Comment: When the problem is caused by a typo, the question ought to be closed.

Comment: @kaya3 under the "Flag" settings, which should be used for closing based on typo?